# Spring data JPA avoid multiple select in many to one relationship

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data JPA and have a many to one relationship from Child to Parent Class using hibernate. I'm writing a search API which would search on child table using some child table columns and return list of child objects along with some data from Parent class for each child object. I'm doing by default eager fetch for many to one relationship. The problem i'm facing is lets say after searching child table 10 entries are returned then hibernate is doing 10 different select queries on parent class to get Parent object for each child object. Is there a way to optimize this ? There is a solution given to similar problem [here](http://jdpgrailsdev.github.io/blog/2014/09/09/spring_data_hibernate_join.html)  but it is for one to many case. I could not find anything helpful regarding this on web also. Any ideas ?

Comment: I'm assuming: You're fetching children.  The child entity is defined with a parent in the class.  The parent is defined with eager fetching.

Given that: You're saying that Hibernate is creating multiple SELECT statements - one per child loaded - to retrieve the parent?  I"d verify this if I were you...

If that's true, I'd just configure the cache for hibernate.  It doesn't have to do that.  I'll dig in a minute for the documentation.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-cache

Answer (score 1):

as you didn't show any codes in the question, it's a little hard to solve it but I think if you specify `join column` (`@JoinColumn` annotation) and use `@OneToMany` annotation in `parent` class(with specifying `fetch` type) and `@ManyToOne` inside `child` you should not have any problem:

```
@Entity(name ="Parent")
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @Column
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name= "paren_id")
    private Set<Child> children;
    //getters and setters
}

@Entity(name ="Child")
public class Child{
    @Id
    @Column
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Parent parent;

    //getters and setters
}
```